# How to debug Oracle 11g packages/procedures in docker with SQL Developer?

Tags: docker, debugging, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm running an Oracle 11g image (https://hub.docker.com/r/oracleinanutshell/oracle-xe-11g) on a docker container.

I'm creating the container with the debug option as explained:

```
docker run --name oracle-xe-11g -idt -p 1521:1521 -p 49161:8080 -e ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true oracleinanutshell/oracle-xe-11g /bin/bash
```

After that I logged in the container as sudo, configured the listener.ora with the correct hostname, everything following this guide (it's in pt-Br, but the commands are easy to understand)

http://loredata.com.br/2017/08/31/rodando-o-oracle-no-docker/

I can connect with SQL Developer and with my main application running in a Wildfly server, but for support purposes I need to debug some package and stored procedures.

I compiled all my packages and procedures to allow debugging, gave the debug permissions to the user, but when I try to debug a procedure in a package using the SQL Developer default debug options I get the following error:

```
Conectando ao banco de dados SFW_DOCKER.
Executando PL/SQL: ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_DEBUG=TRUE
Executando PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '127.0.0.1', '20587' )
ORA-30683: falha ao estabelecer conexão com o depurador
ORA-12541: TNS:não há listener
ORA-06512: em "SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP", line 68
ORA-06512: em line 1
Processo encerrado.
Desconectando do banco de dados SFW_DOCKER.
```

It says there's no listener, but I'm sure everything is running fine.

I also tried to run in ports 4000-4999 exposing them in the create container command and forcing SQL Developer to use them, but I get the same error.

Anyone can help me with this question?

Comment: can the linux container get to your host machine via localhost:20587 ? That's what the debugger is trying to do, reach BACK out from the db to the machine where SQL Developer is running

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you are asking. Both the container and the SQL Developer are running is the same machine, wich is my development workstation. The SQL Developer can reach the container via localhost, and every other application can reach the container as well, hence my database.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe works for all cases.

What you are saying is that my machine needs to expose its ports to the docker container?

Comment: I know the container ip and ports, and I know my machine ip and ports, so instead of trying to connect my SQL Developer to the oracle container exposing the container ip and ports I need to do the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

To solve try:

- Use IPv4 from your local machine
- Set 'Debugging Port Range' from 4000 to 4000
- Check the option 'Prompt for Debugger Host for Database Debugging'

**SQL Developer -> Tools -> Preferences -> Debugger**

[Debugger configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye75g.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting `DatabaseDebuggerDisableJDWP=true` in `ide.properties`. On linux this can be done with this:

```
find ~/.sqldeveloper/ -name ide.properties -type f -exec sh -c "echo 'DatabaseDebuggerDisableJDWP=true' >> {}" \;
```